# Launch dialog on main thread waiting for result of worker thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, cpprest-sdk

I have an app which sends off HTTP requests and processes the received response. The main thread is blocked until a response comes back, else we couldn't process the data. To send these requests, the user must be authenticated. I wish to catch a 401 response and before returning the response for processing by my app, prompt the user for authentication. Depending on the success, I want to retry to send the original request and return *that* response instead, or, if authentication fails, return the original 401 response.

I'm using the C++ REST SDK to send HTTP requests. These happen in another thread (pplx::task). I'm also using MFC modal dialog to prompt for authentication. Some of you may see the deadlock that occurs. If not, let me explain more.

The main thread waits for the HTTP request to complete. Inside that thread, I catch a 401 and wish to launch a dialog. To do so, I use a `boost::signal`. This signal calls `SendMessage` to the handle I wish to display the dialog. After the message is processed by the MFC message loop, it will launch the dialog (on the main thread). This relies on the MFC message loop, which is blocked waiting for the HTTP request. In short, the main thread is already waiting for the request to finish so it can't run its message loop to receive the call from `SendMessage`.

Main thread is waiting on worker thread. Worker thread needs to launch a dialog on main thread before it can continue. Deadlock. Does anyone have any clever solutions for ways around this?

Comment: You definitely want to use threads, but you need to let your UI thread "breathe".  If anything, disable all the controls except for a Cancel button.  Do not "wait" for those threads to complete at a thread basis.  Instead, have them notify the dialog of their result via a method call (or even better, call an "update state" method in the dialog to get more resolution on the state of each thread or percentage of completion or ???).

Comment: Your description is a bit confusing. How many dialogs do you have? Only one (for the authentication) ore more? Also, is the display of the authentication dialog the first action to be taken, or this too must wait for some HTTP request to be completed? Please describe in some more detail, and most importantly in the correct order, the sequence of the desired actions and events.

Comment: For simplicity let's just say there's the main dialog and the auth dialog. Interacting with the main dialog fires HTTP requests. I'm mostly concerned about the authentication expiring and trying to send a request. In practice this should seldom happen. If it does, I want to open the auth dialog and retry the request.

Here's the flow:
User clicks btn in main dialog. Btn fires HTTP. If 200, display response result. If 401, display auth dialog. If success, retry HTTP. If the response is another failure or auth fails, then let's say the program closes.

Comment: So your first action is to display the main dialog. The question is, is the user allowed to do anything in the main dialog if the authentication has not been performed or not? If not, it might be a better design decision to perform the authentication first and display the main dialog only if successful.

Comment: The user can do limited actions without authentication. Most times the user is auto-logged in or prompted when they first start. So normally it's not an issue. However, if the app is open for a long period of time (and wasn't refreshing tokens) the auth could expire meaning their request would fail. At this point they'd have to manually prompt the log-in. And if it happened to fail in the middle of a series of requests, that could be bad by leaving data in an invalid state. Ideally I'd wait for them to log in again, resend the failed request, and continue on its way.

Comment: Then the main dialog should be revised a little. Some UI items (menus, controls etc) should be initially disabled, and enabled only if there is a successful authentication. That is some operations must be enabled depending on the authentication status, which should be tracked. Am I right? Better yet, put in some control indicating the authentication status (eg No Connection, Connecting..., Connected etc). All UI-related operations should best be performed in the context of the main thread, while all HHTP-related ones in the worker threads. The main thread should never be blocked.

Comment: @con: That doesn't buy you anything. You would have to disable those UI items again when the tokens have expired. And the only way to observe, that the tokens have expired is by observing the HTTP response.  By the time you have discovered that the UI should be updated, it is already too late to prevent the user from interacting with the UI that will trigger HTTP requests that will fail.

Comment: Even if I disable buttons until we have authentication that wouldn't change the problem. Say the user logs in successfully. Buttons now are enabled. auth expires. User clicks button. 401. Exactly what @IInspectable said.

Comment: @anon and @IInspectable, worker threads should of course be notifying the main one about any change concerning the authentication status as soon as this takes place (eg by posting a custom message, like `WM_APP + nnn`), and the main thread should update the UI accordingly. Is there something wrong with this design? Is there some better alternative?

Comment: That's what's happening, but the main thread can't respond to the custom message because it's waiting on the result of the worker thread. Unfortunately the app is quite large and would require a lot of rewriting if I were to have HTTP responses send a custom message saying they are ready to update the UI. The request/responses are typically small and happen quickly, so it's not noticeable on the main dialog. But of course becomes rather apparent when it deadlocks.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the PPL. I believe you can chain up continuations, and handle token refresh from there, without blocking the UI. As long as you make sure to guard the section of code that handles token refresh against reentrancy, this should work out fine.

Comment: Well, having the main thread wait for some worker thread to complete is in effect very similar to performing the operation in the main thread. Both result in blocking the main thread. No? It's a matter of UI design specs. If it's acceptable, or else it's too uneconomical to revise the application design, you have to live with this or workaround it. For example, if all you need to do is display an authentication dialog you can do this in a short-lived new thread (it will create a message loop) and better in WinAPI, not MFC.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplist solution here is to redesign the way you are handling your threads.

I suggest that instead of having a single thread for requests, you spawn a new thread for each request and then have it return the status code (no matter what it is), you can then handle any logic for retrying with authentication within your main thread (i.e display an authentication dialog, then respawn the authentication thread with the credentials).

This also allows you to encapsulate your request handler better, which is a big plus. In order to properly encapsulate this logic (so you dont have to check every request) you should define some kind of request handler (either a class or a function). For example

```cpp
StatusCode make_reqeust(...) {
  // Deal with the logic on authentication here
}
```

Where StatusCode is a type for a HTTP status code.

Of course this doesnt solve the issue of your UI thread potentially waiting for your worker thread to finish, so you also need some kind of UI refresh method which is called every x amount of time and which checks the status of all the worker threads (i.e by checking the returned `std::future`'s). You would also want to change my above example to possibly spawn a seperate thread and return an `std::future` in this case.

Comment: Each request does have their own thread. I can always check the status before I process the each response, but I was hoping to handle the 401 case internally so outside I could just worry about the response contents.

Comment: Internally? Like in a function? Or a class?

Comment: Inside of the HTTP request flow. Otherwise I would have to check and prompt for authorization every time I process a request. Ideally I could intercept and process the request (for 401 only) before returning the response which would then be processed for its contents.

Comment: Sure, so put it in a function which returns the final code after possibly retrying with authentication

Comment: I could encapsulate that synchronously, but if an async request is made (returns a thread), the status code isn't known until it's joined. At that point it's ready for processing its content and would put the burden of prompting for authentication on the outside. If I try to do any checks within the thread, we're back to the original problem.

Comment: See my edit on that, probably shouldve explained how to handle the logic in the UI thread :D

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding entirely yet, if I return a future<code>, wouldn't the authorization prompt still be happening within a thread? Even if something on the main thread loops through the futures and prompts for auth there, how would I resend the request to 'change' that future to a 200 instead of a 401?

Comment: The std::future is just an example. It can be used as a path between two threads but so can things like atomic variables. so just have something waiting on a change in the worker thread for example and then act on the credentials passed through